# How to get values from source router dynamically to destination router in apache camel (Here source is kafka topic and destination is rest end point))

Tags: xml, apache-kafka, apache-camel

My idea is to set value "to router" in camel should be according to data from "from router" ,So that it navigates according to "from router" data

I need to get data from kafka topic and set in header of "to router" URI
the data in kafka in HTTP request Obj

In below router configuration i have httpquery , from request i take template value , in same way how to get data from kafka topic and set in "to router header"

```
<from uri="direct:start"/> <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpQuery"> <constant>${header.templateName}</constant> </setHeader> <to uri="http://www.google.com"/>
```

Thanks in Advance